# Empty test suite. No tests executed

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5.5

I use Laravel 5.5 and try to run ExampleTest but I get Empty test suite. No tests executed message. I use phpunit.xml with no changes

What can be wrong and how the problem can be solved?

Comment: Show how you tried to run the test.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you haven't modified ExampleTest, also just to make sure you are using correct phpunit, run it like this:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

(assuming you are using Linux) to make sure you are using correct version of PHPUnit and not for example some legacy version you have installed in your system.

For windows it will be something like:

```
vendor\bin\phpunit.bat
```

to run PHPUnit from the project